# How to geocode a form field on submission?

Tags: 7, location

I'm writing a module with form alter that should geocode a text field value to the lat\lan format upon triggering the submit function. Should I use the [Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module for this? Are there any sample queries to learn how to perform geocoding with that module? Thanks.

Comment: There's an example of how to use it on the module page...

Comment: Cool, so its as simple as:`$point = geocoder('google',$address);
$lat = $point->coords[0];
$lan = $point->coords[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, rather than `form_alter` upon submission, I would wire up an AJAX function to fire on the address/location textfield's onchange event, which would use the [Google Maps Javascript API's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) function.  This would then populate a hidden text field (or two) with the lat/lng pair for form submission.

If you want to use the [Geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/geocoder) module, it should probably go in the validate function so you can double check that you actually have a valid address.

Ideally, you would do both.  Doing it client side is faster, and doing it server side supports users w/o Javascript.